# Link Commerce order with a Customer/Visitor Profile

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have created a Commerce order using the `Sitecore Commerce Connect` OrderServiceProvider and I can see the order details in the `Order Section` of the `Sitecore Commerce Business Tool`

```
var orderService = new OrderServiceProvider();
var request = new SubmitVisitorOrderRequest(cart);
var result = orderService.SubmitVisitorOrder(request);
```

[image]

The order itself works fine, but the problem I have is that the order is not linked or displayed in the `Customer Section` as shown in the image below.
[image]

The Customer Entity ID looks to be matching, but I am not sure why it does not reflect in the Customer Section. Also, the order is not reflected in the  `Sitecore Experience Profile` as well.

[image]

What is the correct way to create an order that is integrated to the Customer Section and Experience profile? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `isRegistered` header value must be set to `true`, otherwise the `CustomerId` will just be act as a text string reference instead of referencing to an actual customer.

More information on [Sitecore Service API Headers](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/service-api-headers.html)

In `Sitecore Commerce Connect Service Layer`, the `IsRegistered` header value is set in `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.EngineConnectUtility` and the value will be based on `Context.User.IsAuthenticated`

```
public static Container GetShopsContainer(string environment = "", string shopName = "", string userId = "", string customerId = "", string language = "", string currency = "", DateTime? effectiveDate = null)
{
    (DataServiceContext)container).add_BuildingRequest((object s, BuildingRequestEventArgs e) => {
        if (Context.User != null)
        {
            e.get_Headers().Add("IsRegistered", Context.User.IsAuthenticated.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    });
    return container;
}
```